# Hacer que Alert se muestre solo al actualizar la app

Tags: java, android, studio, alert

No consigo que el Alert salga solo al actualizar la app, y que ya no vuelva a aparecer hasta que envies otra actualization, dejo todo el código del activity, por que aun añadiendo la ayuda no funciona nada 
PD: no seáis crueles que solo estoy empezando en esto

```js
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView splash1;
    InterstitialAd interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    

    private final int DURACION_SPLASH = 8000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splash1);

        Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.splash).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE).centerCrop().into(imageView2);

        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                interstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-7914603828422129/7396169016");
                AdRequest madRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                interstitialAd.loadAd(madRequest);
                interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded() {
                        if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                            interstitialAd.show();
                        }
                    }
                });

            };
        },DURACION_SPLASH);

    }
```

hasta aqui todo perfecto, el problema llega al meter el dialog y el share, me dice que el contex no esta bien y tampoco le shared

```js
    public static int getFirstRun(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences) {
        int result, currentVersionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
        int lastVersionCode = sharedPreferences.getInt("FirstTimeRun", -1);
        if (lastVersionCode == -1) result = 0;
        else result = (lastVersionCode == currentVersionCode) ? 1 : 2;
        sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("FirstTimeRun", currentVersionCode).apply();
        return result;
    }
    public void showDialogIfUpdate() {
        if (getFirstRun(sharedPreferences) == 2) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext());
            builder.setTitle("Importante");
            builder.setMessage("Este es un programa solo de prueba y no la versión completa");
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
            builder.create();
            builder.show();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Deberias revisar la version de la app del manifiest y deber la ultima version guardada, que se compare, si es distinta, muestre el alert y actualice tu version para que no vuelva aparecer en la proxima

Comment: Bienvenido , añade lo que has realizado o investigado, te sugerimos revisar [ask] y modificar tu pregunta. Es demasiado amplia, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te voy a mostrar como puedes saber si al iniciar tu app es instalada nueva, ya se ha ejecutado o es una actualización y así podrás mostrar el mensaje que quieras cuando quieras...

```
/**
 * @param sharedPreferences preferencia de la app
 * @return -1 Si es la primera vez que se ejecuta, 1 si ya se ha ejecutado y 2 si es una actualización
 */
public static int getFirstRun(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences) {
    int result, currentVersionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
    int lastVersionCode = sharedPreferences.getInt("FirstTimeRun", -1);
    if (lastVersionCode == -1) result = 0;
    else result = (lastVersionCode == currentVersionCode) ? 1 : 2;
    sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("FirstTimeRun", currentVersionCode).apply();
    return result;
}
```

Llamas a ese método y te devuelve un resultado. Le puse un javadoc para que lo entiendas bien salu2

**EDIT**

```
public void showDialogIfUpdate() {
    if (getFirstRun(sharedPreferences) == 2) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext());
        builder.setTitle("Importante");
        builder.setMessage("Este es un programa solo de prueba y no la versión completa");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
        builder.create();
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

Esta variante con **requireContext()** no debe darte problema niguno. Espero que esto te ayude.

**EDIT 2**

Tu sharedPreference se va a llamar **Preference** pero esto es solo un ejemplo para que entiendas. Usaremos ***mContext*** para el contexto, tiene que estar dentro del onCreate, lo defines como una variable de la clase, y lo instancias así:

> mContext = this;

Esto tiene que funcionar:

```
public void showDialogIfUpdate() {
if (getFirstRun(getSharedPreferences("Preference", MODE_PRIVATE)) == 2) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    builder.setTitle("Importante");
    builder.setMessage("Este es un programa solo de prueba y no la versión completa");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
    builder.create();
    builder.show();
}
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me estaba volviendo loco con este asunto :)

Comment: Es un placer poder ayudarte:)

Comment: Bueno aquí va mi pregunta tonta ( aun me queda mucho camino en esto del java) como hago que ese resultado me abra el alert? pondria el javadoc pero no se como se hace jeje ( super principiante en esto)

Comment: Conseguí poner el código arriba :P

Comment: le preguntas if(getFirstRun(sharedPreferences) == 2) ejecutas el alertDialog

Comment: no hay manera de hacerlo funcionar :/

Comment: actualice la respuesta espero que te ayude

Comment: Mañana lo probare, en serio muchas gracias por dedicarme su tiempo :)

Comment: no hay de que... somo una comunidad para ayudarnos :)

Comment: nada no hay manera, seguroq ue estoy teniendo algun error ridiculo, creo que me rendire y volvere a intentar esto un avez este mas avanzado :( he dejado todo el codigo arriba del activity ( lleva intertitial pero omiti esa parte del codigo)

Comment: igual mente te vuelvo a agradecer tu ayuda

Comment: creo que esta vez te tiene que funcionar sin problema alguno @NoobsHardCoders. Espero que si

Comment: Al fin *_^ te debo una muy grande amigo!!!!!!

Comment: me alegro haber podido ser de ayuda :). Puedes considerar votar a favor de mi respuesta me ayudarias ;)

Comment: No me deja votar por que llevo poco en la pag, otra cosa se puede enviar un privado, me gustaria preguntarte algo y no por aqui (aunque si no quieres lo entiendo) ;) saludos

Comment: Claro pero por donde me vas a consultar ?

Comment: Face (Noobshardcoders) , instagram (#nhcoders), email , lo que prefieras

Comment: si usas telegram buscame @Im_Batman99 salu2